# Parse Method Variable Names In Python?

Tags: python

Given the python function:

```
def MyPythonMethod(value1, value2):
    # defining some variables 
    a = 4
    myValue = 15.65
    listValues = [4, 67, 83, -23]

    # doing some operation on the list
    listValues[0] = listValues[1]       

    # looping through the values
    for i in listValues:
        print i
```

How can I extract the `names` and `types` of all the variables in method `MyPythonMethod`?

Ideally, I'd like to get all variable names and their types given a method name. for example, the output for method `MyPythonMethod` will look like this:

`varNames = ["a", "myValue", "listValues", "i"]`

`varTypes = ["int", "float", "list", "float"]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Start digging. http://docs.python.org/library/language.html

Comment: My sense is that although this might not be _impossible_, it is almost certainly unnecessary unless your goal is to create a comically obfuscated rube-goldbergesque contraption. Say more about why you want this and we can probably tell you a better way to do what you want.

Comment: @senderle: I will be getting code from few programmers. in this specific method, I want the programmer to use very specific variable names; hence, I need to know which names have been used in order to make sure they did follow the instruction and did not use other variable names. There will be dozens of files, and it will not be feasible for me to manually check them all.

Comment: You'll have to check it manually if you want to do this reliably. A few quick regexes might help, but they'd be crude and unreliable. Parsing the code and looking through it seems equally impractical. Why is it so important they used precisely these names?

Comment: >>> MyPythonMethod.func_code.co_varnames
('value1', 'value2', 'a', 'myValue', 'listValues')

Comment: Why do you care what variable names they use so long as the function/method produces the desired behavior?

Comment: I don't know what the OP wanted, but I'm interested in this question to help with enforcement of coding conventions.  (Of course, I just want the names... types don't happen until runtime.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[1](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) Variables don't have a type in python. Objects have a type, and variables point to objects.

[2] you can use the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) to get info about the internals of your function. 
   Read the docs -- they will tell you what is available for inspection. 
  MyPythonMethod.func_code.co_varnames will give you the local variable names, for example. 
  ( And note that  MyPythonMethod, as defined, is actually a function, not a method. )

[3] But even when you get the names of the local variables, the aren't bound to any objects 
 except while the function is executing. The value 4 is bound to local var 'a' in the function -- before and after the function is called, there is no 'a' and it's not bound to anything.

[4] If you run the function in the debugger, you can halt the execution at any point and inspect the variables and objects created in the function.

[5] If the function raises an exception, you can catch the exception and get access to some of the state of the function at the time of the exception.

Comment: thank you. it looks like `MyPythonMethod.func_code.co_varnames` returns also the function arguments as part of the list. is there a way to get just the local variables of the method?

Comment: m.func_code.co_varnames[m.func_code.co_argcount:]  may work, but it the count doesn't account for an optional "rest" arg.  I don't know if there are any other cases where argcount wouldn't work. And relying on the arg order may be implementation specific and may not be guaranteed to work in the future.

Comment: Thanks again. Suppose now that the method above also invokes calls to methods of other modules. for example, `os.path.exists(...)`, `sys.exit()` etc. Is it possible to get a list of these methods as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this "from the outside".

- Local variables don't exist until the method runs. Although the scope of all variables is known statically, i.e. at compiletime, I don't think you can get this information easily without crawling through the AST or bytecode yourself. (Edit: Steven proved me wrong about this one... code objects have a tuple containing all local variable names)
- A given chunk of code doesn't have access to any scopes but its own and the sourrounding "lexical" scopes (builtins, module-level globals, local scopes of enclosing functions).
- There is no such thing as the type of a variable (in Python) - any variable can refer to any number of objects of completely different types during its lifetime. What should the output be if you add `a = "foo"`? And if you then add `a = SomeClass()`?

Inside the method itself, you *could* use `locals()` to get a dictionary of local variables and the objects they currently refer to, and you *could* proceed to call `type` on the values (the objects). Of course this only gets you the type of the object *currently* referred to. As hinted in the comment, I doubt that this is useful. What do you really want to do, i.e. what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pdb` can't you set the last line as a breakpoint and then ask the debugger to look at the top stack frame and list the variables for you? Or you could look at the `pdb` code and copy its tricks for how to introduce the breakpoint and then inspect the stack frame beneath the breakpoint function that you register.